# Swap words in a string (Interview question)

Tags: python, string, swap

I came across an interview question without a solution and I couldn't find a solution that meets the memory and runtime requirements.

> You are given a string with 2 words with no spaces and a parameter which is the length of the first word. Your goal is to swap the 2 words in place.
>
> Example: swap_words("stackoverflow", 5) >> "overflowstack"
>
> Time complexity: O(N), Memory complexity: O(1)

I managed to solve it using a recursion:
First I moved the shorter word to its place and then repeat the process with the longer words.

```
swap_words("stackoverflow ", 5)
stackoverflow >> rflowovestack 

swap_words("rflowove", 3)   # 13-5-5
rflowove >> oveowrfl        ###  ove-owrfl-stack 

swap_words("owrfl", 2)      # 8-3-3
owrfl >> flrow              ###  ove-flr-owstack

swap_words("flr", 1)        # 5-2-2
flr >> rlf                  ###  overlfowstack
```

The stack of calls here is obviously not O(1) memory.

Another solution I saw somewhere was to mirroring the entire string and then mirroring each word separately:

```
stackoverflow >> wolfrevokcats
wolfrevo--kcats >> overflow--stack
```

This is much better in my opinion but I am not sure how to swap character in a string in place without using an extra space. I am writing in Python and as far as I know Strings are immutable.
So the only thing I can think of is convert the string to a list of characters do the swap and create a new string out of it.

So what am I missing here? Is there a solution for that problem under those requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way in my opinion would be to slice the string like this:

```
def swap_words(word, n):
    return word[n:] + word[:n]
```

Comment: When you slice a string you actually create a new one so your solution is also using an extra of `O(N)` memory.

Comment: I'm not super good at complexity, but would it not still be `O(1)`? As in there's always going to be just 2 slices no matter the length of the string. Perhaps the time complexity is `2n` with doing two slices, but `2n` that becomes `O(n)` anyway.

Comment: @user1692261 does it? What does `O(1)` even mean with memory? `O(N)` is used for operations, not memory. Does it mean 1 extra byte? That would mean in-place modification, but Python strings are immutable. This means using a modifiable buffer. Which means either creating a copy of the original string or using `ctypes` to modify the bytes directly. A rather dirty solution

Comment: @user1692261 or does `O(1)` mean a fixed multiple of the original, the same thing it means for operations?

Comment: I have no on to ask to verify the answer but as far as I understand, if `N` is the length of the string, then creating a new string (or buffer) in the same length means extra `O(N)` memory. `O(1)` means that you may use a constant number of variables like a `temp` variable in the famous swap to integer problem.

Comment: One other thing to bear in mind too actually - a large point of Python is having readable code. I reckon they'd be looking for something like this, because in the real world this is easily maintainable. A super complicated solution to save a few bytes of memory would be a nightmare for whoever has to take over your code in the future.

Comment: I see what you mean about the memory, but like you said about strings being immutable, it's impossible to not end up with 2 copies of the string. Swapping 2 letters at a time will result in the same memory footprint, but more time complexity, as its having to reconstruct the new string at each step. Basically my code is doing the exact same thing, but instead of one letter at a time, its just doing an entire chunk at once.

Comment: I guess that this question is not intended to be solved in Python. Maybe in C :)